# Firestore - How many Documents can I retrieve in one Collection request?

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I wasn't able to find anywhere the limit to the number of documents I can get in one Collection get. Say I have 1,000,000,000 docs... Is that even possible? And if I tried to get them all, would it actually give me an array of 1,000,000,000?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There's essentially no limit to the number of documents you can store in a collection or retrieve in one request.

That said, there are plenty of reasons why retrieving a trillion documents at once would be a bad idea -- things like cost, bandwidth and free space on the client would start to factor in here. So if you really want to store a trillion documents in a collection, you probably want to add a `limit` to your queries.

Comment: Those are the answers I like, simple, clear and helpful, thank you!